# What's the difference in E4X between the elements() and children() method

Tags: javascript, rhino, e4x

I'm currently working with Javascript Rhino and E4X.

Is there a difference between using elements() and children() besides the possibility to use an additional argument in the elements method to get only elements with that name.

Example:

```
new XML(<x><a><q/></a><b/><c/></x>).children();
new XML(<x><a><q/></a><b/><c/></x>).elements();
```

Kind regards,
Aeonnex

Comment: text nodes are children but not elements ... i.e. children include all elements and text nodes ... elements won't include text nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jaromanda X pointed out:

> text nodes are children but not elements ... i.e. children include all elements and text nodes ... elements won't include text nodes – Jaromanda X

So in the following example there is a difference between the elements() and children() method:

```
new XML(<x><a><q/></a><b/>abc<c/></x>).children()
/*
<a><q/></a>
<b/>
abc
<c/>
*/

new XML(<x><a><q/></a><b/>abc<c/></x>).elements()
/*
<a><q/></a>
<b/>
<c/>
*/
```